# docker restart policy doesn't work?

Tags: docker

docker 1.10.2, ansible 2.0
I'm setting all containers to restart_policy:always.

When I'm doing a simple

```
service docker restart
```

and not all containers are up (every time different set of containers are up) - assuming this is applicative level (I have dependencies - for example zookeeper) - shouldn't the "failed" ones keep trying? isn't it all what this is about?

did docker inspect:

```
 "State": {
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 143,
            "Error": "initlogger: Failed to initialize logging driver: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:24224: getsockopt: connection refused",
            "StartedAt": "2016-05-23T13:22:55.849986549Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2016-05-23T13:39:58.087484408Z"
        },
        "Image"
```

Comment: What is the RestartPolicy for these containers?  You don't show it in your question.  `docker inspect -f '{{ .HostConfig.RestartPolicy }}' <container>` will yield `{<policy> <maximum_retires>}`.

Comment: my bad - we had restart_always_retry=5 - once removed - works as expected.